# Get all Blobs From Azure Storage using .NET Core 2.2

Tags: c#, .net, azure, asp.net-core

Very quick question regarding fetching list of blobs from Azure Storage (or to be more precise from container)

As I'm using **.NET Core 2.2** and async streams are not allowed in C# 7.3 version:

```
 await foreach (BlobItem blobItem in containerClient.GetBlobsAsync())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\t" + blobItem.Name);
    }
```

So I tried with something like this but without any luck (stabbing in the dark)

```
List<BlobItem> items = new List<BlobItem>();
Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => items.Add(await containerClient.GetBlobsAsync()));
```

So I'm wondering what's the alternative to await foreach syntax in C# v7.3

Thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [`AsyncPageable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.asyncpageable-1?view=azure-dotnet) returned by `GetBlobsAsync()` exposes an `IAsyncEnumerator<T>` that you can use to iterate using a simple `while` loop:

```
Azure.AsyncPageable<Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models.BlobItem> blobs = containerClient.GetBlobsAsync();
IAsyncEnumerator<Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models.BlobItem> enumerator = blobs.GetAsyncEnumerator();
try
{
    while (await enumerator.MoveNextAsync())
    {
        Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models.BlobItem blob = enumerator.Current;
        // use blob
    }
}
finally
{
    await enumerator.DisposeAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a more compact syntax available to do this than the while loop option,

```cs
AsyncPageable<SecretProperties> allSecretProperties = client.GetPropertiesOfSecretsAsync();

await foreach (SecretProperties secretProperties in allSecretProperties)
{
    Console.WriteLine(secretProperties.Name);
}
```

Example is taken from the [azure sdk docks](https://azuresdkdocs.blob.core.windows.net/$web/dotnet/Azure.Core/1.5.1/api/Azure/Azure.AsyncPageable-1.html)

Comment: Sorry but the question asked was how to do this using C# 7.3. 

With C# 7.3 async streams are not available so the code you propose `await foreach` will not work for the question that was asked.